# How can I make list items display in two columns from a specific point?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I show items 01 to 07 on first column, and 08 to 10 items (which is not enough to fill in the first column) on second column?

I have a very simple navigation bar, like the following:

```css
.test ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.test ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.test ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.test li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C
      <ul>
        <li>C01</li>
        <li>C02</li>
        <li>C03</li>
        <li>C04</li>
        <li>C05</li>
        <li>C06</li>
        <li>C07</li>
        <li>C08</li>
        <li>C09</li>
        <li>C10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

if you run in local, you can see that not all 10 items could show in one screen.

So, I have a solution, which is to make items 8-10 show in the second column, which align with items 1-3, but I don't know how to do it in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, max-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap:.25em;
}

li {
border:1px solid grey;
padding:.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>C01</li>
  <li>C02</li>
  <li>C03</li>
  <li>C04</li>
  <li>C05</li>
  <li>C06</li>
  <li>C07</li>
  <li>C08</li>
  <li>C09</li>
  <li>C10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Points are awarded as a result of votes by the community. Unless there's abuse, it's up to you to improve your question so that its value to the community is more apparent, after which it will probably receive more votes.